# Unable to reach child elements using right angular bracket

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, css-selectors

Here is what I am trying to do

```
$("table:nth-of-type(1) > tr:not(tr:nth-of-type(1))").hide();
```

Anyone knows why jQuery does not support such a way of selection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because the rows are not children of the table, they are children of the `tbody`:

```
$("table:nth-of-type(1) > tbody > tr:not(tr:nth-of-type(1))").hide();
```

Even if you don't have a `tbody` tag in the HTML, a `tbody` element is created for the `tr` tags that are directly in the table.

Comment: unfortunately the table structure is dirrerent. it's <table><tr><td>.

Comment: @AlexHerrmann The browser will automatically insert `tbody` elements, though.

Comment: @AlexHerrmann: That's the structure of the HTML code, but not the structure of the elements that are created from it. If you inspect the elements in the browser, you will see that it has added a `tbody` element to put the `tr` elements in.

Comment: Thank you very much! The issue is solved ;)